# How to use email template 'password_new' after setting the password

Tags: magento-1.9, email-templates, password

For resetting password **`account_password_reset_confirmation`** email template is used, you can find it here:

```
app/locale/nl_NL/template/email/account_password_reset_confirmation.html
```

and can set **Admin >> System >> Configration >> Advanced >> Admin >> Admin User Emails**. That is fine, After setting the password I want to send an email with new password, for that purpose **`password_new`** email template can be used, located:

```
app/locale/nl_NL/template/email/password_new.html
```

But I don't know how to use it. Where should I set it, or I have to do it manually?

**Edit-1 :**
My bad, **`password_new`** is my local template name, create by using **`Remind Password`** provided by magento

Comment: Is your problem resolved now (after the edit)? I'm not quite sure if there are any open questions.

Comment: Are you asking how to trigger an email to be sent?